# How to implement panning like google maps in SVG

Tags: svg, zooming, jquery-svg, panning

I have done zooming in SVG  chart. Please refer below screenshot.

[image]

above screenshot series is zoomed state.i used clipping concept to hide the outside lines from chart area after zooming.

i need to do panning here ? how can i implement like google maps. when i start pan to move the series and see the zoomed chart of another area.
how can i perform "translate"  operation for path element in SVG.  element in the screenshot is called series (i.e. data points /line).

i need to move the  element zoomed area based on mouse movec(i.e. like scrolling the hidden content).

Is "translate" attribute is used to view the other zoomed area ? how can i perform "translate"  in path element that will make the panning.

Normal chart screenshot.

[image]

Zoomed Screenshot.

[image]

Please refer below link.

http://www.cyberz.org/projects/SVGPan/tiger.svg

Thanks,

Siva

Comment: Have you tried looking through the javascript for the svg you linked? http://www.cyberz.org/projects/SVGPan/SVGPan.js

Answer (score 0):

First be sure:

Download svgpan.js file in your project location

is must be the right place in your code

You must add this: xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"